# Logically equivalent conditionals, same test, but different condition coverage (google test)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, gtest

Title pretty much says it. I ran into trouble getting condition coverage of a logical statement and found that the order in which the statement is written (rather than order of operations) results in different condition coverage. The equivalent statements are the following. I'm using google test.

```
if (A && (B || C)) 
{
    do x
}

if ((B || C) && A) 
{
    do x
}
```

For both if statements I have the same three test cases, and I've bolded the conditions which I *think* get evaluated by gtest.

For the first if statement:

1. A = **true**, B = **true**, C = false
2. A = **true**, B = **false**, C = **false**
3. A = **false**, B = false, C = true

For the second if statement:

1. B = **true**, C = false, A = **true**
2. B = **false**, C = **false**, A = true
3. B = **false**, C = **true**, A = **false**

The second if statement results in full condition coverage (since A, B, and C get evaluated as true AND false), but the first does not.

Could this be considered a bug? Technically conditions in parenthesis should evaluate first, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

That being said I don't think this behavior could result in things being missed, but could result in more test cases than necessary depending on how your logical statements are ordered, so maybe it's not a bug.

Is there a reason for this behavior that I'm missing? Much appreciated!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation ?

Comment: that confirms what I expected was going on, so it seems like a c++/c behavior rather than a google test behavior. Thanks Erik!